# How to get Location name from Hierarchical data in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table `Location` like this:

```
ID,   PID,   Location
1    NuLL    Country
2    1       City
3    2       County
4    3       District
5    4       Social
```

How can I make a view  in MySQL that returns this:

```
ID,   Location,   Full Location
1     Country     Country
2     City        City-Country
3     County      County-City-Country
4     District    District-County-City-Country
5     Social      Social-District-County-City-Country
```

Comment: Please, no one care about this question?

Answer (score 0):

Is the depth number variable?
I mean can there be 'something else'-Social-District-County-City-Country
or the Social-District-County-City-Country is the deepest case?

It seems you want a recursion that is not available in MySQL.
Check out this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104187/mysql-hierarchical-queries